# How to update release artifacts in Maven?

Tags: maven

I have the following case:
- Maven project compiles fine on one machine where artifact A (release one) exists in that machine's local Maven repository,
- artifact A was removed from the remote repository.

How can we be sure that the project builds fine on a new machine where local Maven repository is empty?

Comment: If you depend on an artifact it need to be in a remote repository when you build from a clean slate. So why did you remove it and why can't you put it back?

Comment: I'm not sure that I fully understand your problem, but: If you connect to a remote repository with artifact A, Maven fetches it and puts it into the local repository before the build. If you do not have a remote source for your artifact, you can install it manually into the local repository of your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the install task `install-file` to put the jar into your local repo from your local hard drive:

> ```
> mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>
> ```

See [maven.apache.org](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Few cases :

- One, if you own `artifact A` and use `<repository>` to keep the versions in sync. You can anytime rebuild your project on the new machine to fetch the artifact.
- Second, If `artifact A` is owned by you and you didn't use repositories until now, you can simply bump up its version and deploy it on the remote server(`<repository>`) and consume the new version on the machine where you want to. Use `<repositories>` in your pom.xml to specify the remote path as follows :

  ```
  <repository>
     <id>clojars</id>
      <name>Clojars Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://clojars.org/repo/</url>
  </repository>
  ```
- Third, if you don't own the `artifact A` and it exists in a public maven central repositories, all you need to do is rebuild the correct dependency to fetch it over the net.
- Worst case, the `artifact A` used is owned by you and doesn't exist in a public central repository. You can still copy-paste the jar file using any mode and move it to the machine's `/m2/repository` where you require it. But do note in such case you shouldn't reach this case ever again.

Also in the last case, you can copy it into your project and use it as suggested by @Adam

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>
```